# C# WPF Serial Port Reading data continuously

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, serial-port

I'm trying to build a WPF application that would read data from Serial Port and would not block UI thread, but I'm a bit stuck at how I should do it.

I got code as follows in my *.xaml.cs file

```
private void testConnection_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string correctPort = "COM6";
    SerialPortConnection serialPortTestConnection = new SerialPortConnection(correctPort);

}
```

In my SerialPortCommunications I got it like this:

```
public SerialPortCommunications(string comPort)
{
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort(comPort);
        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 2400;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 7;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mySerialPort.Encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();
        mySerialPort.WriteLine("C");
}

private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    String s = sp.ReadExisting();
    if (s == "\r")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tempReadingString);
        tempReadingString = string.Empty;
    } else
    {
        tempReadingString += s;
    }
}
```

I do get the first response from the device, however it stops after that even though the port stays open. I know for sure that passing value "C" continuously returns values (tested with Hyperterminal).

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking you should avoid using ReadExisting, it has known issues, particularly when the incoming stream contains binary data. Here's what I do:

```
this.SerialDevice = new SerialPort(this.Port);
this.SerialDevice.BaudRate = 115200;
this.SerialDevice.DataReceived += OnDataReceived;
this.SerialDevice.Open();
...
private void OnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var serialDevice = sender as SerialPort;
    var buffer = new byte[serialDevice.BytesToRead];
    serialDevice.Read(bytes, 0, buffer.Length);

    // process data on the GUI thread
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
        ... do something here ...
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put an object of your class SerialPortCommunications in a new thread and then start reading data from a COM port. Also if you need data from the COM port in WPF for example TextBlock you need to create an event in the class SerialPortCommunications, and in the WPF to implement an event handler. But in that handler you will need to use Dispatching for showing data in that TextBlock.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried adding it in a Thread like so:

`
            Thread test = new Thread(() => {
                SerialPortConnection serialPortTestConnection = new SerialPortConnection("COM6");
            });
            test.Start();
`

However no luck, it returns just once response and seems to be disconnecting, then if I connect again it does return value once again and stays connected this time.

Comment: Never create threads directly in C#, if you do decide to run code in a different thread then use tasks instead. Stephen Cleary's book "Concurrency in C# Cookbook" is basically the bible on this and has this to say: "As soon as you type new Thread(), it’s over; your project already has legacy code."